# Appending a csv file

Tags: vb.net, csv

```
Dim NumberOfRecords As Integer

Sub Main()
    Call ListTowns()

End Sub

Sub ListTowns()
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MyFormat As String = "{0,  -22} {1,  -16} {2,  -8} {3,  -8}"
    FileName = "Towns.csv"

    Dim AllRecords As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FileName)

    Dim TownList = From record In AllRecords
        Let field = record.Split(",")
            Select New With {.Name = field(0), .County = field(1), .Population = field(2), .Area = field(3)}

    For Each Town In TownList
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(MyFormat, Town.Name, Town.County, Town.Population, Town.Area))
    Next
    NumberOfRecords = TownList.Count
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Sub AddRecord()        
    Dim FileName As String

    FileName = "C:\Users\Omar\Desktop\Towns.csv"
    FileOpen(1, FileName, OpenMode.Random)
    Dim NewRecord As String


    Console.WriteLine("Enter the record you want add")
    NewRecord = Console.ReadLine()
    FilePut(1, NewRecord, NumberOfRecords + 1)
    FileClose(1)
    Console.WriteLine("The record has been added")
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

At the moment the program can list the contents of the csv file however with regard to the `AddRecord()` Sub, when I input the data `Test,Test,Test,Test` it is adding this record to the file properly and is overwriting the first record.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you read the `Related Topics` linked on the right ? When you ask a new question on SO, intellisense will suggest you some possible related topics. It's always worth reading them..

Comment: I have, but they don't really answer my question especially as I am working in the console, and they are all using forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenMode.Random is used for reading/writing files that have a **fixed** width record.  It is unclear from your post if you actually have fixed width records (my hunch is you don't).  At any rate, to properly read/write in random mode you'd have to declare a structure that defines the length of each record and also tell the system the length of the record when you open it (so that it can move that many bytes to the desired record position you want to read/write!).  Follow the links listed in this page titled [Random File Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711474(v=vs.71).aspx) to learn how to do this.

If you don't actually have fixed width records, but instead have variable length records (one record per line, and the lines are different lengths), then you can simply store all the lines in a List(Of String) and add the new record to the end of the List.  Now you simply overwrite the entire file with [System.IO.File.WriteAllLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx), similar to what you did with ReadAllLines().  With this approach, you can modify any of the records in the List and then simply overwrite the entire file to update the physical file.

Here's a quick example of what the second approach might look like:

```
Module Module1

    Public AllRecords As New List(Of String)
    Public FileName As String = "C:\Users\Omar\Desktop\Towns.csv"

    Public Sub Main()
        LoadTowns()
        ListTowns()

        AddRecord()

        ListTowns()
    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadTowns()
        AllRecords.Clear()
        AllRecords.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FileName))
    End Sub

    Public Sub ListTowns()
        Dim MyFormat As String = "{0,  -22} {1,  -16} {2,  -8} {3,  -8}"
        Dim TownList = From record In AllRecords
            Let field = record.Split(",")
                Select New With {.Name = field(0), .County = field(1), .Population = field(2), .Area = field(3)}

        For Each Town In TownList
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(MyFormat, Town.Name, Town.County, Town.Population, Town.Area))
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddRecord()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the record you want add")
        Dim NewRecord As String = Console.ReadLine()
        AllRecords.Add(NewRecord)
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(FileName, AllRecords.ToArray)
        Console.WriteLine("The record has been added")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it using lists now, however as I am using two procedures(one for displaying the csv data on the console and one for adding a new record to a csv file) I am getting an error in the second procedure that the file is being used by another process