# Adding records to a csv file

Tags: vb.net, csv

I am trying to make a procedure to add a record to the end of a csv file

```
Sub AddRecord()
    Dim NewRecord As String

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the record you wish to add")
    NewRecord = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Done")
    Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(FileName)
        writer.WriteLine(NewRecord)
    End Using
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

If NewRecord = Test,Test,Test,Test the program does this

Town, County,Pop, Area

Berwick-upon-tweed, Nothumberland, 12870, 468

Bideford, devon, 16262,430

Bognor Regis, West Sussex, 62141,1635

Bridlington, East Yorkshire, 33589, 791

Bridport, Dorset, 12977, 425

Cleethorpes, Lincolnshire, 31853, 558

Colwyn bay, Conway, 30269, 953

Dover, Kent, 34087, 861

Falmouth, Cornwall, 21635, 543

Great Yarmouth, Norfolk, 58032, 1467

Hastings, East Sussex, 85828, 1998Test,Test,Test,Test

But I want Test,Test,Test,Test to be added on the record after the hastings record, how do I fix this?

Comment: You have to take care of the `,` yourself. Just cause it is a `csv` file type it does not know where they go.

Comment: I have sorted that but I mean that it is not adding the record at the bottom of the file where it should be

Comment: because you are making a new streamWriter and overwriting the file with each call to this AddRecord sub.

Comment: This code is getting rid of everything in the file how do i get it to just add the newrecord at the end?

Comment: Duplicate of [Appending a csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078998/appending-a-csv-file)

Comment: Sorry, I did this one because the other question was using the wrong code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File operations are fast. Do not use any stream at class level. Open, add, close. [File.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText({path})
  sw.WriteLine({record})
End Using
```

Comment: That almost does it is just that rather than making a new record, it puts the text at the end of the last record. How do I correct this?

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you want, could you add an example in your original post of how it would look?